# Pass in Custom Parameter to devise.en.yml to use in Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-i18n

I've got to make an update to a rails app using Devise to show the number of minutes left if you are locked out while trying to login to the application.

In the devise.en.yml file I've got:

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
    failure:
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      inactive: "Your account is not activated yet."
      invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      locked: "Your account is locked. Please try again in %{number_of_minutes} minutes"
      last_attempt: "You have one more attempt before your account is locked."
      not_found_in_database: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      timeout: "Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue."
      unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
```

I have the variable called 'number_of_minutes' in the locked: error message but no matter what I try I get:

`missing interpolation argument :number_of_minutes in "Your account is locked. Please try again in %{number_of_minutes} minutes" ({:resource_name=>:user, :authentication_keys=>"E-mail address"} given)`

I've added it to the view, the overridden SessionsController, set default locale, tried a whole bunch of online recommendations and no luck.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Adrian

Comment: Hi, Adrian, could you please show your view code?

Comment: Yml file is above and in the view I have:

```<%= I18n.t 'devise.failure.locked', number_of_minutes: '1' %>```

Comment: Hm seems correct. Do you still face this error?

Comment: Yes, it happens when the account is locked out (eg 3 wrong password attempts)

```missing interpolation argument :number_of_minutes in "Your account is locked. Please try again in %{number_of_minutes} minutes" ({:resource_name=>:user, :authentication_keys=>"E-mail address"} given)```

Happens here

```@@missing_interpolation_argument_handler ||= lambda do |missing_key, provided_hash, string|
raise MissingInterpolationArgument.new(missing_key, provided_hash, string)
```

And the provided_hash variable contains

{:resource_name=>:user, :authentication_keys=>"E-mail address"}

Answer (score 1):

The variables has to be passed as a Hash, not just a value.

In your view, you should try to call the translation with :

```
I18n.t 'devise.failure.locked', number_of_minutes: <value>
```

Replacing  with the variable you need